# Back-calculate raw vaules from vegan decostand()?

Tags: r, vegan

Does anyone know if you can get raw values back after they have been standardized with vegan's decostand() fun (knowing what method was used initially)? Basically, I had to transform values with method='range' to get a model to run but now I want plot outputs to show raw predictor values.

Comment: We need more detail on this (ideally a reproducible example), like what data you have, what model you run, how you produce your outputs... Maybe you could get away with just relabelling your plot x axis from 0...1 to the original predictor range, but I'm just guessing here.

Comment: You mean you overwrote your original data and they are no longer available? If you have your original data, just use that in plotting.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using a simple linear regression on with the original and scaled data as a first pass. But nice to know of the newly added decobackstand() to the github version

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to backtransform data, because needed information is not stored with the result object. For range, we would need original extremes (minima and maxima) for each column or row transformed.

I can have a look at adding this information as attributes to transformed data, but it won't help you retrospectively.

Comment: Github version of vegan returns now information needed for back-transformation (when possible), and provides function `decobackstand` for the task. It won't help you, though, because you should have produced your standardized data with this new software to have back-transformation. Future generations, perhaps.